# Is it possible to extend a SAP-Standard field in a Fiori-App with a VH?

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am currently researching the possibility to extend a SAP-Standard field for example in the SAP Product Master Fiori-App with a value help (onPremise S/4HANA) (which does not exist there by default). I've tried using Metadata Extensions but I am not sure if I am on the right track.

Is it even possible to achieve what I am trying to do or are there any other possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: could you give the name of the app you are talking about?

Comment: The App ID is F1602, but this is just one example. Technically it should be similar for other Fiori Apps, right?

Comment: Any news from your side?

Comment: The extension methods are highly dependent on the specific application version and the location of the field within the app.